# IIS is overloaded with service requests

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-10, wcf

I have a Windows 2012R2 server with IIS10 on it. We've been running a wfc service on it for a few years but lately it's giving time out messages.

I looked at the performance monitor and it shows quite a few requests in the queue.

[image]

If I understand correctly, it's due to the programs calling the api is not closing the connection properly and it's leaving it open, thus the queue builds up.

The only way I have found to resolve this is to fix the code calling the api and putting out a mass update.

This is going to be a problem as we have a lot of computers using this software.

Can I change IIS to reset the connection after X seconds if it is idle? I don't want to use this as a work around but I need it to start responding until I get this fixed and an update out.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

It was suggested that I change these setting in IIS:

[image]

[image]

I applied these changes and ran `iisreset` since I wasn't sure if it needed to be restarted after these changes. If didn't make a difference in the number in my queue.

Comment: if it's an API server, you can decrease keep-alive duration or even disable it altogether. See [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/) or [limits.connectionTimeout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits).

Comment: @mforsetti thank you for your response. I have both of those settings set to 4 and it didn't make any difference.